# Why var initialized with number set to Int32

Tags: c#, numbers, int, var

I am not sure, if this is right place to ask this question.
Moderator can move this question to appropriate place if required.

I have question in C#.NET

I have below class with overloaded methods,

```
public class A
{
 public void GetNumber(short n)
 {
 }

 public void GetNumber(int n)
 {
 }

 public void GetNumber(long n)
 {
 }
}

A a = new A();
a.GetNumber(100);
```

so it will call method with int parameter, 
My Question is Why it will call method with int Parameter.

also on similar lines,

```
var n = 100;
```

in this case data type of n will also be set to int.

Why not short or other numeric data type.

Is there any logic/reason behind this or its just Microsoft has set this default standard for number data type.

Comment: Wait, what? I don't see any `add` method in your `A` class

Comment: Yes it's as simple as this: the compiler - by specification - interpretes every number literal (that fits in an `Int32`) as `Int32`. To make it use a different type there are symbols like `m` for `decimal`, `L` for `long` etc... or you need to cast explicitly.

Comment: @Rafalon Sorry updated the code